# Is it true we can run programs without kernel?

Tags: kernel

I just read the below sentence from the book "The Linux Programming Interface",

"Although it is possible to run programs on a computer without a kernel, the
presence of a kernel greatly simplifies the writing and use of other programs, and
increases the power and flexibility available to programmers. "

Is it true we can run programs without kernel. please give me some proper explanations.

Comment: *"Is it true we can run programs without kernel"* -- Not quite.  You can execute one standalone (i.e. self-contained)  (aka bare-metal) program on a CPU at a time.   Executing more than one program at a time (i.e. concurrently) would require a scheduler (i.e. a kernel).

Comment: A kernel is also a "program". Which indeed executes itself without a kernel :-) It is an highly specialized program that provides abstract APIs to other running programs and maintain some properties (security isolations, memory management, low level tasks like network stacks, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can run a program on a computer, without a kernel.

But this means you will have to do everything yourself.

The computer usually boots some kind of BIOS and then finds somewhere something to start. (Bootsector, boot from USB, Network, ... )

What this boot code contains can be a kernel, but it could also be your application.

Your application will then be responsible to handle everthing, and the list is big:

- Interrupts
- Hardware IO
- Devices
- Memory (RAM) management
- CPU scheduling
- Neteork IO
- Disk IO
- Videocard
- HDI (Human device interface / Keyboard/Mouse/Brail/... )
- Audio
- ...

So technically this is possible, but usually this isn't what your primary focus will be (Unless you are writing the next big OS)